# Temporarily disable user?

Tags: deployment

We use continuous deployment to deploy changes to our production host. At the same time we would like to prevent access to the deployment account, except during specific deployment windows. At the moment the solution we are looking at is simply renaming the .ssh folder.

Is there another approach that could be used or another approach to limit deployments outside of allocated windows?

This is for Ubuntu.

Comment: what flavour of unix is this? E.g. with PAM you could setup something with `pam_time`. Also what happens if they stay logged in past the window?

Comment: This for Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable a user by using:

```
usermod -e 1 <username>
```

This will cause the account to immediately expire

To re-enable the account use:

```
usermod -e "" <username>
```

According to `man usermod`, the `-e` option sets the expiration date for the account. When set to empty it disables the expiration.